# Governing body - керівна рада, керівний орган чи керівне тіло?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Згідно https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/body слово *"body"* окрім тіла людини чи тварини може вживатись також у значенні групи людей, зокрема у виразі *"governing body"* як колегіального органу влади.

Який український іменник найкраще підходить для перекладу виразу *"governing body"* як друге слово після прикметника "керівний/керівна": **рада**, **орган** чи **тіло**?

Якщо приміром обрати варіант *"керівний орган"*, то чи не буде він вводити у замішання, адже прикметник *"керівний"* ще не вказує в якому саме значенні вживається слово *"орган"*, тобто про який саме *"керівний орган"* іде мова?

Якщо ми говоримо приміром *"орган влади"*, то зрозуміло, що це не орган людського тіла (навіть якщо перед словом "орган" не вживаємо жодного прикметника скажімо "місцевий"). А якщо говоримо *"керівний орган"*, тоді здається подвійне значення залишається, адже мозок приміром як орган тіла теж можна назвати *"керівним органом"*. І тоді про який саме *"керівний орган"* іде мова стає зрозуміло лише з контексту.

Чи є в даному випадку найкращим варіантом перекладу вираз *"керівна рада"* подібно як "рада директорів"?

Comment: Органи державної влади?

Answer (score 1):

Мені здається, те, що *керівний орган* може означати і орган тіла людини, і установу, — цілком нормально. По-моєму, це цілком гармонійне узагальнення одного й того самого значення. (Як-от *голова* може бути не лише в людини, а й, наприклад, *міський голова* (*голова міськради*), *голова спілки* тощо; *ніс* може бути не лише в людини, а у корабля; тощо.) Тому *керівний орган* я вважаю найкращим варіантом. У «Генеральному регіонально анотованому корпусі (ГРАК) української мови» версії 16 *керівний орган* [траплається 5654 рази](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&cql=%22%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%20%22%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%22&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1).

*Керівна рада* — часто теж вдалий варіант, по-моєму, але є одна важлива деталь… Наскільки я розумію, керівний орган — це теоретично не завжди рада, він може мати якусь іншу внутрішню структуру (бути не зібранням учасників, де рішення приймаються колегіально, а мати якусь іншу внутрішню організацію). Утім у випадках, коли керівний орган — це справді рада (а найчастіше, як я розумію, це так), я не бачу недоліків у варіанта *керівна рада*. У ГРАК-16 *керівна рада* [траплається 158 разів](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&cql=%22%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%20%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%22&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1).

Ще «Українсько-англійський словник ділової людини» (Є. Гороть, О. Василенко, Н. Єфремова та ін., 2014) [пропонує варіант](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=governing+body&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) *правління* — часто теж цілком доречний, по-моєму. (Хоча я не певен, що *керівний орган* у 100% питань можна замінити на слово *правління*. Наскільки я розумію, керівний орган може відповідати й за якусь конкретну сферу, а не лише здійснювати загальне керівництво, наприклад, *керівний орган з питань таких-то*; а *правління* особисто в мене найбільш асоціюється саме з верховним керівництвом.) У ГРАК-16 слово *правління* в різних значеннях [траплається 117159 разів](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&cql=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%22&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1).

А от *керівне тіло* — по-моєму, найгірший варіант. Хоча слово [тіло](http://sum.in.ua/s/tilo) має багато значень (це не лише тіло людини, а й, наприклад, фізичне тіло), але от *тіло* у значенні «установа» кажуть вкрай рідко (на відміну від слова [орган](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=67092&page=2120), де «установа» — одне з безпосередньо зазначених у словниках значень). У ГРАК-16 *керівне тіло* [траплається 4 рази](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=cql&cql=%22%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%20%22%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%22&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1).

Answer (score 1):

[Великий англо-український словник 2011](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=body&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)

**body [ˈbɒdɪ] n (pl bodies)**
**18.** група людей;
a ~ of electors виборці;
in a ~ у повному складі;
the ~ of people більшість людей;
**19.** орган; товариство; асоціація; ліга; рада; корпус;
an advisory ~ консультативний орган;
autonomous ~ies органи самоврядування;
diplomatic ~ дипломатичний корпус;
the government ~ адміністративна рада;
legislative ~ законодавча влада;
learned ~ учене товариство;
standing ~ постійний орган;
subsidiary ~ допоміжний орган;
~ of politic держава;

Тобто "governing body" можна перекласти як "керівний орган", "керівна рада" тощо.

Answer (score 0):

Найкращий варіант - "керівний орган". Можна казати "орган влади", або просто "органи", якщо із контексту зрозуміло, що це саме **керівні** органи. Із внутрішніми органами їх ніхто плутати не буде. Можна казати "керівна рада", але я такого не чув. "Керівне тіло" - це **неправильно**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).